# Уведомление в группе персональное / самоудаляющиеся

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, popup, alert

Третий день листаю telegram bot api и так не придумал (не нашел метода) способа как это реализовать..

**Необходимо:**

Когда пользователь присылает сообщение в ГРУППУ бот на него реагирует и отвечает персонально человеку (т.е. сообщение видит только этот человек) либо какое то всплывающее сообщение, которое само пропадет.

**Есть идея:** 
Отправлять обычное сообщение ботом в группу, а потом через n секунд его удалять.

**Отбросил:**

`sendChatAction` - Нельзя написать свое сообщение, а так бы идеально подходило (либо я не туда смотрю).

`answerCallbackQuery` - Не подходит, т.к. сперва должна быть нажата кнопка..

`ReplyKeyboardMarkup`, `ForceReply` - с помощью параметра `selective` можно персонализировать сообщение, но используется метод `sendMessage` где поле `text` обязательно и такое сообщение будет отображаться в группе для всех.

Если я где то не прав - поправьте. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможно в будущем появится (будем надеяться) метод для подобной функции. В данный момент реализовал удаление сообщений через n секунд.

Answer (score 1):

если пользователь пишет сообщение "не печатает принтер" в группе, оно попадает под хэндлер:

```
# regex не печатает принтер
@bot.message_handler(regexp=".*((?:не|принте(?:р|ра|ры|ров|ру)) (?:печа(?:тает|т|та|тае|тате|ает|тат)|не) "
                            "(?:принте(?:р|ра|ры|ров|ру)|печа(?:тает|т|та|тае|тате|ает|тат)))")
def regex_printer(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'supergroup' and message.from_user.id not in users:
        message.text = search_name_host(message.from_user.id)
        if message.text is not None:
            autoprinter_2(message)
```

выполняется функция, если удалось проверить принтер ответ будет в группу, если произошла ошибка в ЛС

отправка в группу (если успех):

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(data))
```

отправка в ЛС (если произошла ошибка):

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ошибка:\n{}'.format(error))
```

Comment: А как отправить пользователю ЛС? Если пользователь отдельно не запустил бот и если это не группа со вступлением по заявкам и ботом в качестве администратора?

Comment: Отправка в ЛС из группы - `message.from_user.id`, из чата с ботом - `message.chat.id`.
Бот не может писать первым пользователю - пользователь обязательно должен начать диалог с ботом или быть в группе, где так же присутствует бот

Comment: Если просто писать ботом-администратором участнику группы у меня выдает "Forbidden: bot can't initiate conversation with a user". Мой бот может писать только если группа закрытая и пользователь вступил по приглашению с одобрением. Что я делаю не так в обычной группе?

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос дополнив его кодом.